# torch.cuda.memory_stats and torch.cuda.memory_snapshot return empty data structures

Tags: pytorch

According to [this pytorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#memory-management), the commands `torch.cuda.memory_stats(device="cuda")` and `torch.cuda.memory_snapshot()`
should return a dict and a list with content.
However, the first gives me `OrderedDict()` and the second `[]`

Why is that?

`torch.cuda.is_available()` returns `True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not using gpu memory, for example, try start a kernel and
implement this code:

```
import torch
print(torch.cuda.memory_stats(device="cuda"))
print(torch.cuda.memory_snapshot())
x = torch.randn(10, 10).to('cuda')
print(torch.cuda.memory_stats(device="cuda"))
print(torch.cuda.memory_snapshot())
```

The first will give you empty dict and list, while the last will give the statics you want